# Using “ser” without "un/una"?

Tags: gramática, artículos, cópulas

How come you can sometimes see phrases like “Es broma” or “Es muy linda ciudad”? Why is "un/una" left out?

Answer (score 11):

That's an interesting use of *broma*. You know that the verb *ser* does not need an article when the word following is an adjective:

> El coche es azul.
>   Ha sido divertido.

In the case of [*broma*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=68hKX8j), the word is classified as a noun by the RAE. An example of this usage:

> Aquello fue una broma que me gastó mi hermano.

But in such sentences like *es broma*, that's a fixed expression that uses *broma* as an adjective. What you are saying is just that what happened has the quality of being a joke. This probably comes from the adverbial expression *de broma* or *en broma*. You can say that something *es de broma*. Dropping the middle preposition *en/de* is something that has been done at least since the 19th century in Spanish, as seen by some texts found in the CORDE:

> *—Paz, caballeros —dijo Calpena con gracia—. No me riñan aquí o a los dos les mando a la calle.
>
>   —Es broma.
>
>   —Jugamos, nos divertimos.*
>
> Benito Pérez Galdós, "Mendizábal", 1898 (Spain).

This way of adjetivizing a noun (or a expression) is most probably what you see in your second example, *es muy linda ciudad*.

As stated by the RAE's grammar, what happens with *broma* also happens with *verdad*, I would add *mentira*, both are nouns but you can say *es verdad* or *es mentira*.

Comment: In the second sentece, did you mean _ser_ doesn't need _an article_?

Comment: @Rafael indeed. Maybe I had in mind the expression _ser de broma_, hence the mistake. Thank you for noticing!

Comment: Note that a similar thing happens with uncountable nouns, like in the sentences *"esa comida es porqueria"* or *"Antonio es buena gente"*, even though those are clearly nouns, there's no article.

Comment: The answer by @ukemi is much more convincing for me.  I have a hard time accepting the adjectivization explanation.

Answer (score 6):

There are indeed cases in Spanish in which the zero article is used with singular, countable nouns.

The examples at issue can take an indefinite article:

1. Es **(una)** broma.
2. Es **(una)** muy linda ciudad.

(1) seems to be a case in which the countable noun drops the article to become a category, almost as if it were an adjective, as opposed to "ser verdad":

- No es verdad, es broma. (It's not true, it's a joke.)

In (2) the noun "ciudad" seems to be information that is already known. The new information is the adjective phrase "muy linda". A similar case would be:

3. Ana es muy linda mujer. (The fact that Ana is a woman is indisputable. I'm just telling you that she's very beautiful.)

It is worth noting that an article can also be used in this case:

3'. Ana es **(una)** muy linda mujer.

Another example which has just come to mind is, in reference to the gender of a person:

4. ¿Es nena o varón? (Is is a girl or a boy?)

In this case, the noun is definitely used as a category, being equivalent to "female or male", and will not usually accept an article.

Comment: And actually "verdad" is a noun, where the actual adjective is "verdadero/a", so that is an example that is used every day with little thought, as you've illustrated here!

Answer (score 4):

Well, saying "Es broma" is different from saying "Es una broma".

"Es broma" means "Just kidding"/"I'm joking" but with the "una" it means "It's a joke".

Answer (score 2):

> #### 3.3.5 Omission before singular nouns: general
>
> *Un/una* is often omitted before singular count nouns. This happens whenever the
>   generic or universal features of the noun are being emphasized. Compare *Pepe
>   tiene secretaria* 'Pepe’s got a secretary' (like many bosses) and *Pepe tiene **una** secretaria que habla chino* 'Pepe’s got a Chinese-speaking secretary'. Section 3.3.6—9
>   covers some of the cases in which this type of omission occurs.
>
> #### 3.3.6 Not used before professions, occupations, social status, sex
>
> This is a common case of the phenomenon described in 3.3.7: *un/una* is not used
>   before nouns which describe profession, occupation, social status, and it is often
>   omitted before nouns denoting sex. In this case the noun can be thought of as a sort
>   of adjective that simply indicates a general type:
>
> - *Soy piloto/Son buzos* I’m a pilot/They’re divers
> - *Es soltero/Es casada* (compare *está casada* 'she’s married'; see 29.4.1a) He’s a bachelor/She’s a married woman
> - *Se hizo detective* (5) he became a detective
> - *...y aunque Alejandra cm mujer...* (F. Sébato, Arg.) ...and although Alejandra was a woman...
>
> But nouns denoting personal qualities rather than membership of a profession or
>   other group require the article: compare *es negrero* 'he is a slave—trader' and *es un
>   negrero* 'he’s a ”slave-driver”' (I.e. makes you work too hard); *es carnicero* 'he’s a
>   butcher (by trade)’, es un carnicero 'he’s a butcher (i.e. murderous)’; *es Supermán* ’he
>   is Superman’, *es mi supermán* 'he’s a superman'; *el sargenta se decía: "No es un ladrón. Es un loco"* (M. Vargas Llosa, Pe.) 'the sergeant said to himself "he’s no thief. He’s a madman."'
>
> If a noun of the type discussed above is qualified, it usually become particularized (non—generic) and therefore requires the article. Compare *Es actor* ’he's an
>   actor’ and *Es un actor que nunca encuentra trabajo* ’he’s an actor who never finds
>   work’; *me han dicho qua usted es un hombre que se ha quedado solo* (A. Bryce Echenique,
>   Pe., dialogue) ’they tell me that you are a man who has found himself alone’. But
>   the resulting noun phrase may still be a recognized profession or generic type, so
>   no article will be used: *soy profesor de español*. See 3.3.9 for discussion.
>   The article is used if it means 'one of...': ' - *¿Quién es ese que ha saludado? — Es un profesor* '"Who was that who said hello?" "He’s one of the teachers"'.
>
> #### 3.3.7 Omission of the indefinite article with ser and nouns not included in 3.3.6
>
> Omission of the indefinite article after *ser* is frequent (a) in certain common
>   phrases, (b) in literary styles: a rare English counterpart is the optional omission of
>   'a’ with ’part’: 'this is (a) part of our heritage’ *esto es (una) parte de nuestro patrimonio*. Omission is more common in negative sentences and apparently more
>   frequent in Peninsular Spanish than in Latin-Anmrican. In the following phrases
>   omission seems to be optional, and it produces a slightly more literary style:
>
> - *Es (una) coincidencia* It's a coincidence
> - *Es (una) cuestión dc dinero* It’s a question of money
> - *Es (una) víctima dc las circunstancias* (S)he's a victim of circumstances
>
> However, no clear rule can be formulated since the article is retained in other common phrases like *es una lata* (colloquial) ’it’s a nuisance’, *es una pena* ’it’s a pity’, *es un problema* ’it’s a problem’, *es un desastre* ’it/(s)he’s a disaster’, *ha sido éxito* ’it was a success’. Omission may occur after a negative verb even though it is not usual after the positive verb:
>
> - *No es molestia/problema* It’s no bother/problem
> - *No es exageración* It’s no exaggeration
> - *No as desventaja* It’s not a disadvantage
>
> In other cases, omission often, but not always, produces a literary effect:
>
> - *La codorniz es # ave tiernísima* (M. Delibes, Sp.) The quail is an extremely tender bird (to eat)
> - *Es # mar de veras* (M. Vargas Llosa, Pe. dialogue) It’s (a) real sea
> - ¡Éstá/Esta es # cuestión que a ustedes no les importa!* (J. Ibargüengoitia, Mex, dialogue) This is an affair that has nothing to do with you!
>
> In all the above examples the appropriate gender of *un* or *una* could have been
>   used at the points marked with #, but the original texts do not use the article.
>
> (i) If the following noun is not generic but merely implies the possession of certain
>   qualities *un/una* must be used: *el hombre es un lobo para el hombre* ’man is a wolf to
>   man’ (but. not a member of the wolf species), *Mercedes es un terremoto* ’Mercedes is
>   an earthquake’ (ie. a hell—raiser), *está hecho una foca* ’he’s got really fat’ (*la foca* = ’seal’—the animal).
>
> (ii) Omission of the indefinite article before a qualified noun tends to produce an
>   archaic or heavily literary effect (or it makes the sentence sound like stage instructions), as in *entra una señora con sombrero verde con plumas de avestruz* ’a lady with a green hat with ostrich feathers comes in’, where ***un*** sombrero verde would nowadays be much more normal. Where Unamuno wrote, in the early 20th century, *era
>   un viejecillo [...] con levitón de largos bolsillos* ’he was a little old man in a large frock-Coat with deep pockets’, a modern writer might prefer ***un*** levitón.
>
> <sup>NB: In formal literary styles, omission of *un/una* is normal in definitions when the subject comes first: *novela es toda obra de ficción que... 'a novel is any work of fiction that...'.</sup>

- [A New Reference Grammar of Modern Spanish, 4th Edition](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mEfKAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA41)

Comment: ¿Cómo haces para copiar texto de Google Books?  Nunca he logrado hacer eso.

Comment: @aparente001 suelo hacer un 'screenshot' y pegarlo en un sitio de [OCR](https://www.google.com/search?q=ocr+paste+online)

Comment: He usado ese truco para los pdf estúpidos que no permiten buscar texto.  No se me ocurrió que un jpeg u otra imagen se podría procesar de igual manera.  Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Lo explicaré en español.

Se omite "un/a" generalmente en el lenguaje coloquial para que genere globalidad al asunto. *"Es una broma"* quiere aclarar que puede usarse *"Perdona, solo es una broma"* o *"Lo siento, es una broma"*; y en el caso de *"Es broma"* sería lo mismo pero cambiaría la forma de verse, por ejemplo: "Es broma, ¿verdad? " o "¿Lo que me dices es broma?", "¡Que es broma¡".

La segunda frase tendría más sentido como *"Es muy linda la ciudad"* o *"La ciudad es muy linda"*, pero como he dicho se usa mejor en lenguaje coloquial.